# Postgres does not works

Tags: macos, postgresql, sockets, localhost, mamp

postgres.app does not work, after installation i try to start server, return this error:

> Could not start PostgreSQL server.
>
> pg_ctl: could not start server
>
> Examine the log output.

Here's the log:

> 2017-10-26 20:09:45.136 CEST [592] LOG:  could not translate host name "localhost", service "5432" to address: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
>
> 2017-10-26 20:09:45.136 CEST [592] WARNING:  could not create listen socket for "localhost"
>
> 2017-10-26 20:09:45.136 CEST [592] FATAL:  could not create any TCP/IP sockets
>
> 2017-10-26 20:09:45.137 CEST [592] LOG:  database system is shut down

Same problems running on MAMP.
I'm using MacOSX Sierra 10.12.6

Comment: Chevk your file `/etc/hosts`. It should have an entry `127.0.0.1.  localhost`. If not, use `sudo` and the editor of your choice to add such a line.

Answer (score 0):

either you dont have the localhost entry on your host file

```
C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts
```

Or another app is already using the port 5432

In Mac

```
/private/etc/hosts
```

https://www.tekrevue.com/tip/edit-hosts-file-mac-os-x/

Comment: Mmm... `C:\Windows` would be an awful thing to have on a Mac.